# What do ‘redda', 'the taste of babat', 'Kottu Aiya', and ‘Kunu kaaraya’ mean? (From "The Seven Moons of Maali Almeida")

Tags: meaning, shehan-karunatilaka, the-seven-moons-of-maali-almeida

I am translating *The Seven Moons of Maali Almeida* and am confused about the following sentences:

- "those knots were looser than your Amma's redda." What does 'Redda' refers to?
- "this is why, Kottu Aiya, you and me need to put a swim." In 'Kottu Aiya' is Aiya modal particale? Or a family name? But the full name is Kottu Nihal.
- "'Kunu kaaraya' is a euphemism for those..." what does 'Kunu kaaraya' refer to?
- "He relieves the taste of babath marinated in old arrack." Does 'babath' refer to a local dish of curried cow stomach?
- "Balal Ajith was known to boil cats or balalas and serve..." Does 'balalas' mean the name of a local dish in Sri Lanka? If so, what are its ingredients and cooking steps?
- "You don't disagree with the Headless Atheist." What does 'Headless Atheist' mean? A particular subcategory of Atheism?
- "The only god you ever believed in was a low-caste yaka called Narada." 'Yaka' is a position of a traditional dancer wearing a mask, isn't it?
- "To be the impotent homo, the ponnaya, as the dead kid at the counter just called you." What does 'The ponnaya' mean?

So many local cultural terms that I am not quite familiar with.

Comment: What have you already tried to understand these terms - dictionaries, search engines, reference books, etc.? What do you still not understand about these terms after consulting such resources?

Comment: Were you not happy with my answer or did you delete it all accidentally?

Comment: Sorry to make you confused. I delete it to keep it confidential. Your answers are supremely helpful. Much appreciated!

Comment: You don't really get to ask a question on a publicly available Q&A site and then try to control who can read the answer. I have rolled back your question so that it again includes all the terms you originally asked for help with, without which much of the accepted answer makes no sense. Literature SE is a resource for future readers, not just for those who ask the questions originally,

Comment: There is nothing confidential about published literary texts.

Answer (score 5):

- *‘Amma’s Redda’*

  According to [this blog](http://kiyumkerum.blogspot.com/p/sinhala-slang.html) about Sinhala slang:

  > Redda (රෙද්ද) - Means cloth (female garment). Offensive use is quite similar to the usage 'Shit' in English although no similarity in the literal meaning. (e.g. 'Mona reddak da!' (මෙ‍ාන රෙද්දක්ද!) means 'What the hell!' and 'Thoge Aachchige redda' (තොගෙ ආච්චිගෙ රෙද්ද) means 'Your grandma's garment')

  The inference probably being that his mother has loose sexual morals and sheds her clothes readily.
- *‘Kottu Aiya’*

  [This site](https://singternet.fandom.com/wiki/Aiya) indicates that the meaning of ‘Aiya’ is:

  > a tag generally showing disregard.

  The book makes clear a little later on that the ‘Kottu’ part is a nickname from time working in a prison kitchen. [Kottu](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kottu) is a dish that requires roti to be chopped up with blades. He used these blades as weapons.

  > Kottu, is made up of paratha or godamba roti, which is cut into small pieces or ribbons. Then on a heated iron sheet or griddle, vegetables and onions are fried. Eggs, cooked meat, or fish are added to fried vegetables and heated for a few minutes. Finally, the pieces of cut paratha are added. These are chopped and mixed by repeated pounding using heavy iron blades/spatula, the sound of which is very distinctive and can usually be heard from a long distance. Depending upon what ingredients are used, the variations are vegetable, egg, chicken, beef, mutton, and fish kottu roti. It is often prepared and served as a fast food dish.

  My reading is therefore that when Balal Ajith calls him ‘Kottu Aiya’ he is just being generically insulting to him.
- *'Kunu kaaraya’*

  Reverting to the KiyumKerum Blogspot linked earlier, that site uses the word ‘Kunu’ when describing a collective term for highly taboo sexual slang:

  > These terms are collectively called kunu harupa in Sinhala which literally means 'dirty/rotten utterings'.

  And defines ‘kaaraya’:

  > Use of Kaaraya (කාරයා)
  >
  > Sinhala language has an all purpose suffix Kaaraya (කාරයා) which when suffixed to a regular noun (which denotes a demographic group, etc), creates an informal and disrespectful reference to a person of that demographic group. Most native speakers of Sinhala liberally use this suffix when they chat informally. However they also make great effort to avoid Kaaraya when they speak in a formal venue.
  > e.g.
  >
  > polis-kaaraya (පොලිස්කාරයා) – policeman
  > thæpel-kaaraya (තැපැල්කාරයා) – postman
  > mura-kaaraya (මුරකාරයා) - watchman
  > bora-kaaraya (බෝරාකාරයා) - a Bora Muslim person
  > American-kaaraya (ඇමෙරිකන්කාරයා) - an American

  My reading is that these two terms therefore combine into a derogatory reference to people dealing with things that are unclean/taboo.
- *’babath’*
  From [Wikipedia on Sri Lankan cuisine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sri_Lankan_cuisine):

  > Babath
  >
  > Babath or offal consists of the stomach of cattle or goats. It is cooked as a curry or deep fried and eaten with rice or more famously with Pittu. Its origins are associated with the Sri Lankan Malay community but it is very common among the Moor community as well
- *‘Balalas’*

  In this case it turns out that the author was providing the translation. According to Google translate, Sinhala for ‘cat’ is ‘balala’. He pluralises it as we would in English, to ‘balalas’ rather than the Sinhala ‘balalan’.  He got his nickname because he had a reputation for cooking cats.
- *‘Headless atheist’*

  This was introduced just about five pages earlier:

  > CHAT WITH DEAD ATHEIST (1986)
  >
  > You have seen dead bodies, more than your fair share, and you always knew where the souls had gone. The same place the flame goes when you snuff it, the same place a word goes when you say it. The mother and daughter buried under bricks in Kilinochchi, the ten students burned on tyres in Malabe, the planter tied to a tree with his entrails. None of them went anywhere. They were, and then they were not. Just like all of us won’t be when our candles run out of wick.
  >
  > The wind takes you and the world swings by at the speed of a rickshaw, faces and figures flutter past, some less terrified than others, most with feet that don’t touch the ground. You have one response for those who believe Colombo to be overcrowded: wait till you see it with ghosts.
  >
  > ‘Are you following that thing?’
  >
  > It is an old man with a hook for a nose and marbles for eyes, who appears to be travelling the same wind. His head is not between his shoulders as heads prefer to be. It is held with both hands in front of his stomach like a rugger ball.
- *’Yaka*’

  ‘Yaka’ is a [demon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Demons_of_Sri_Lanka) rather than a dancer:

  > Demons, more commonly known by their Sinhala names yakseya and yakka (Sinhala: යක්ෂයා/යකා), form an important part of Sinhalese folklore in Sri Lanka. They are under the rule of a king, who has forbidden them to kill humans. Therefore they bring down various diseases upon humans, so that they can gain the satisfaction that they are denied because of this ban. Victims who are believed to have been affected by demons then have to be cured and the demons repelled through exorcism rituals.
- *’Ponnaya’*

  Again referring to the KiyumKerum blog, it gives this definition:

  > Ponnaya (පොන්නයා), Ponsiya or Pontiya - Umbrella term for all submissive Transgender people, Eunuch, or submissive male homosexual. Abusive word for any submissive behavior.

Answer (score 2):

The above answer with translation is almost correct.

These words are local words in Sri Lanka, where I am from as well as Mr. Shehan Karunatilaka, the author of Seven Moons of Maali Almeida. I have read these very phrases in the book.

In local language,

- Amma's Redda: A slang to say "Rubbish!", or "What the hell" (Redda is the clothes)
- Kottu Aiya: In this book it is a nickname of someone who makes local street food called Kottu. (The real meeting of Aiya is brother, but it can be used for a close person elder than someone)
- Kunu Kaaraya: Garbage collector
- Babath: It's the dish referred in the question
- Balalas: Balala is cat in the local language. Balalas has been modified by adding 's' to make it sounds plural in English. But in the local language the plural should be "Balallu". (In the book, this kind of word is used because sometimes in society such versions created for fun)

  Important to note that cat meat is never eaten in Sri Lanka.

  According to the book, both Kottu Aiya and Balal Ajith are thugs who have been imprisoned. This explains how they have gained these nicknames. Kottu Aiya shreds rotty to make in the prison kitchen while Balal Ajith is famous for making a dish out of cats for prison mates. This cat dish is definitely not a part of the prison menu, but an illegal dish among thugs-mates as their weird delicacy.
- Headless Atheist: is another character in the book, resembles another victim
- Yaka: Devil / local deity in charge of evil
- Ponnaya: Slang referring to a transgender person, in an insulting way :(